# a.e. limit and $L^p$ coincide if both exists?

Tags: probability-theory

Assume you have a sequence of square integrable R.V. $(X_n)$ converging a.s. and in $L^2$ do their limits have to coincide?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Yes, but it's not that obvious. That has to be proved. For example, if a limit in $L^p$ exists then it can be shown (it's a pretty standard result) that there is a subsequence converging to the $L^p$-limit almost surely.

Comment: Another way to see this (that requires a bit more machinery): both $L^p$ convergence and a.e. convergence imply convergence in the sense of distributions, and the topology of distributional convergence is still Hausdorff so limits are still unique in that space.

Comment: I think it clicked now. If they would be different then $X_n$ couldn't converge in probability. Thanks.

Comment: @User8128 perfect answer